# Detect when instance has completed setup script?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm launching instances using the following command:

```
gcutil addinstance \
--image=debian-7 \
--persistent_boot_disk \
--zone=us-central1-a \
--machine_type=n1-standard-1 \
--metadata_from_file=startup-script:install.sh \
instance-name
```

How can I detect when this instance has completed it's install script? I'd like to be able to place this launch command in a larger provisioning script that then goes on to issue commands to the server that depend on the install script having been successfully completed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of ways: sending yourself an email, uploading to Cloud Storage, sending a jabber message, ...

One simple, *observable* way IMHO is to add a `logger` entry at the end of your `install.sh` script (I also tweak the beginning for symmetry). Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/logger "== Startup script START =="
#
# Your code goes here
#
/usr/bin/logger "== Startup script END   =="
```

You can check then if the script started or ended in two ways:

- From your [Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), select "Projects" > "Compute" > "VM Instances" > your instance > "Serial console" > "View Output".
- From CLI, by issuing a `gcutil getserialportoutput instance-name`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do all of this within `gcutil addinstance`.

I'd suggest:

1. Adding the instance via `gcutil addinstance`, making sure to use the `--wait_until_running` flag to ensure that the instance is running before you continue
2. Copying your script over to the instance via something like `gcutil push`
3. Using `gcutil ssh <instance-name> </path-to-script/script-to-run>` to run your script manually.

This way, you can write your script in such a way that it blocks until it's finished, and the ssh command will not return until your script on the remote machine is done executing.

Comment: Last time I checked, this wouldn't work, as the startup script is launched in background. The vm will be in "RUNNING" status way before the startup script has ended, if you try a "sleep 3600".

Answer (score 1):

There really are a lot of ways to accomplish this goal.  One that tickles my fancy is to use the metadata server associated with the instance.  Have the startup script set a piece of metadata to "FINISHED" when the script is done.  You can query the [metadata server](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#waitforchange) with a hanging GET that will only return when the metadata updates.  Just use [gcutil setmetadata](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#updatinginstancemetadata)
from within the script as the last command.

I like this method because the hanging GET just gives you one command to run, rather than a poll to run in a loop, and it doesn't involve any services besides Compute Engine.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you only access the metadata server from *within* the instance itself? From the docs: "You can query a metadata server only from its associated instance."

Comment: Good point - you have to use setcommoninstancemetadata to make project-level metadata.  Then you can access it using gcutil from outside the instances.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to both set and retrieve the metadata from outside the instance? It looks like the only way you can see the metadata is through `gcutil getinstance myinstance1`, which isn't really in a parseable format.

Comment: gcutil getproject <projname> --format json will include the commoninstancemetadata in a parseable format.  You can then dump the existing key:value pairs to a file, and add the new key:value pair at the end, then load it with gcutil setcommoninstancemetadata --metadata_from_file.  I am getting less fond of my proposed solution as we go through the details, but I still think it works in principle.

Answer (score 1):

One more hacky way:

```
startup_script_finished=false
while [[ "$startup_script_finished" = false ]]; do
    pid=$(gcloud compute ssh $GCLOUD_USER@$GCLOUD_INSTANCE -- pgrep -f "\"/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup\"")
    if [[ -z $pid ]]; then
        startup_script_finished=true
    else
        sleep 2
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to have your install script create a text file in a cloud storage bucket, as the last thing it does, using the host name as the filename.

Your main script that did the original gcutil addinstance command could then be periodically polling the contents of the bucket (using gsutil ls) until it sees a file with a matching name and then it would know the install had completed on that instance.